# curl not returning content length header

Tags: php, curl

Trying to get image file size using curl but content length header is not returned:

```
$url ="http://www.collegefashion.net/wp-content/plugins/feed-comments-number/image.php?1263";
$fp = curl_init();
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_REFERER,'');
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0');
$body = curl_exec($fp);
```

var_dump($body):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 02 May 2010 02:50:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.63 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: W3 Total Cache/0.8.5.2
X-Pingback: http://www.collegefashion.net/xmlrpc.php
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
```

It works via ssh though:

```
curl -i http://www.collegefashion.net/wp-content/plugins/feed-comments-number/image.php?1263
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 02 May 2010 03:38:43 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.63 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: W3 Total Cache/0.8.5.2
X-Pingback: http://www.collegefashion.net/xmlrpc.php
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 347
Content-Type: image/png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CURLOPT_NOBODY makes a HEAD request while your command line with -i is a GET request...

If you'd use -I with your command line version they would be more similar.

Comment: thanks! that was it. the head request doesnt return content length with that server.

Comment: Just to add: some servers simply refuse HEAD requests and return a status code of 405 (i.e. "Method not allowed")

Answer (score 0):

Check **[`curl_getinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)**:

```
$size = curl_getinfo($fp, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
```

Execute it after `curl_exec()`.

<strike>One other option is to set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `false` and just do `strlen($body)`</strike> -- ignore this, I didn't noticed you were using `CURLOPT_NOBODY`.